# Any software like blend for HTML5 canvas animation?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-animation

Is there any software available like blend, for working with HTML5. Especially, to do animation related stuffs.

Comment: Adobe Edge seems to do what you want, Hopefully soon: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FnNtX73v8k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like http://raphaeljs.com/ might be useful

Comment: that link was really nice. But, I couldn't find any information about any software or IDE like Microsoft's Expression Blend for doing animations in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

Hype allows you to make animations in HTML5.  Pretty bare-bones at the time of writing but they seem to be planning to implement most of the functionality that Flash and Expression Blend offer.

http://www.tumultco.com/hype/

(I realize this is an old question but at the time of writing there still doesn't seem to be a good HTML5 flash/blend alternative.)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this free illustrator plugin which converts any drawing into canvas, also can do animation and interactivity too:

http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/