# Is there editor/IDE/RDE software for html/javascript canvas?

Tags: html, frameworks, canvas, editor

I have seen some very interesting wrappers and libraries for canvas, like [RaphaelJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780974/any-software-like-blend-for-html5-canvas-animation), [FarbicJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/3477169#3477169), [ProcessingJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/3474969#3474969), [CakeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/3487762#3487762), [ThreeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/5200496#5200496), [CantoJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/3481943#3481943), [jCanvaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/5054176#5054176), [Akihabara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram/3560531#3560531), [jCotton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2735199/588973), [InfoVis](http://thejit.org/), [LibCanvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735199/what-are-the-frameworks-for-creating-html5-canvas-applications/3774729#3774729) and seen some vectorgraphics editors, that use canvas element, but is there any graphical "editor" (web UI or hardcoded) that would allow draw a vectorgraphic using lines, splines, shapes, and images, that would output JavaScript/canvas code (just like [FabricJs demo](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/), but much more enchanced), to draw that, what I have made in editor. That would ease creation of canvas graphics for maaaany steps, cause currently, using console, to write, execute, see changes, change stuff, reset, execute, see changes... takes forever, for more complex graphics, not mentioning animation stuff.

I guess, [Sencha Animator](http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/) is closest I could find, but it is made for CSS animations, and considers WebKit, as it's base (and it is still in development phaze), and I could not find, what output it has.

Can't see if Mozilla's [Thunderhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572740/are-there-any-gui-toolkits-built-on-top-of-html-canvas-like-swing-swt-gtk-or-qt/1574058#1574058) is that, what I want. What do you think about something more serious, like [Ample SDK JavaScript UI Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572740/are-there-any-gui-toolkits-built-on-top-of-html-canvas-like-swing-swt-gtk-or-qt/4118621#4118621)? What will be future for [Tempest game engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572740/are-there-any-gui-toolkits-built-on-top-of-html-canvas-like-swing-swt-gtk-or-qt/3295876#3295876), noone knows... Sadly, [Rocket Pack](http://rocketpack.fi/) engine was acquired by The Walt Disney Company in March 2011, and no licensing for it, is avilable for community...

So, what are you using, to create canvas animations/graphics, like [Androidify](http://androidify.com/)? Maybe, you are suggesting any of tools/libraries mentioned above?

My aim is to find some framework or library, that would allow create canvas animations for creating html games, just like Zynga facebook flash games. I don't want to overuse canvas, just for some interactive animations and other "heavy" stuff, that is hard to do, with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, this is answered in another question [Editor for Drawing canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470485/editor-for-drawing-canvas)

- http://www.htmlcanvasstudio.com/
- http://canvimation.github.io/
- http://fabricjs.com/

I guess, my question was too complex or not given clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made an Adobe Illustrator-to-canvas plugin that should suit your needs:

http://visitmix.com/labs/ai2canvas/

(Well, assuming you have Illustrator...)